# Simplifaction of Negative Fractional Exponent for Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm self learning calculus and I ran across this question during my practice.

The question asks to differentiate the following equation:

$$\sqrt{x^3 + \csc(x)}$$

Now, I was able to do the following...

$$(1/2(x^3 + \csc(x)))^{-1/2}\cdot\cot(x)\cdot-\csc(x) + 3x^2$$

Basically, I applied the chain rule

However, when I looked at the solution, I was only partially correct. My numerator was right, but the denominator was wrong. The solution provided was

$$\frac{3x^2-\cot(x)\csc(x)}  {2 (\csc(x) + x^3)^{1/2}}$$

I am confused as to how the "two" comes into the denominator. Doesn't $1/2$ as an exponent imply a regular square root? The negative in the exponent makes it a fraction and the $1/2$ just makes it a regular square root . Thus, I'm thinking there is no reason for the "2" to be there at all, becuase it's a regular square root.

Hoping someone can clear this up.

Thanks

Comment: I tried fixing your MathJax. Check out [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to check it out.

Comment: However, I think I messed up the paratheses and/or the exponents. Make sure to double check if what is written there is still what you initially got.

Comment: right.    $\sqrt x = x^{\frac 12}$ and the derivative is $\frac 12 x^{\frac 12 -1}=\frac 12 x^{-\frac 12} = \frac 1{2\sqrt x}$.  The $2$ comes from the power rule.  $(x^k)' = kx^{k-1}$.  In this case $k =\frac 12$ so.... a $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: You do realise that $(3x)^2$ is equal to $9x^2$?

Comment: @mrtaurho I will thanks.

Comment: @fleablood perfect, makes sense, thanks

Comment: @TonyK that was an error, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited it.

Comment: No you haven't!

Comment: @TonyK you're right, I haven't. There were two instances of it and I only edited the second one. Changed the first one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=x^3+\csc(x)$.

By the chain rule, you need
$$
\frac{d}{du}\sqrt{u}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{2}\sqrt{u}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{du}{dx}(x^3+\csc(x))=3x^2+\cot(x)\csc(x)
$$

---

Notes.

$$
\frac{d}{du}u^{1/2}=\frac12 u^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{2}\sqrt{u}}
$$

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Power rule (with a power of $\frac 12$): $(x^k)' = kx^{k-1}$.  So if $k =\frac 12$ then $(\sqrt x)' = (x^{\frac 12})' = \frac 12 x^{\frac 12 -1} =\frac 12 x^{-\frac 12} =\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$

So by chain rule:

$(\sqrt{x^3 + \csc(x)})'=$

$\frac 1{2\sqrt{x^3 + \csc(x)}}\cdot( x^3 + \csc(x))'=$

$\frac 1{2\sqrt{x^3 + \csc(x)}}\cdot(3x^2  - \csc(x)\cot (x))=$

$\frac {3x^2  - \csc(x)\cot (x)}{2\sqrt{x^3 + \csc(x)}}$